# Unusual occurrence with database function

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a simple function to send some form values to a database and keep getting a syntax error that I can't seem to solve. I've tried 19 different variations of the code and still, I get the same error.

```
<?php

    function sendData () {
    $con = mysql_connect("XXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXX");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("user", $con);
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'], $con);
        $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age'], $con);
        $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'], $con);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'], $con);
        $revenue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['revenue'], $con);
        $expenses = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['expenses'], $con);
        $marketing = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['marketing'], $con);
        $advertising = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['advertising'], $con);
        $sql = "INSERT into users (name, age, phone, email, revenue, expenses, marketing, advertising) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$phone', '$email', '$revenue', '$expenses', '$marketing', '$advertising');
        mysql_query( $sql , $con );
        mysql_close($con);
        }


    sendData();
?>
```

Comment: Look at your syntax highlighting.  Or in other words, "The wrong quote in the right place can make all the diff-erence in the world, Mr. Freeman."

Comment: I'm getting these errors now: 
$marketing = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['marketing'], $con);
          
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/content/88/10880688/html/smartkrawl/processor.php on line 41

Comment: The data is being sent to the DB, at least some of it, but I keep getting error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you are missing a double quote at the end of the string:

```
    $sql = "INSERT into users(name, age, phone, email, revenue, expenses, marketing, advertising)
        VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$phone', '$email', '$revenue',
                '$expenses', '$marketing', '$advertising')";
----------------------------------------------------------^
    mysql_query( $sql , $con );
    mysql_close($con);
```

The more serious problem is that you are using "mysql_" functions and putting the parameter values directly into query.  You should be using "mysqli_" or PDO and using parameterized queries.  Now is the time to learn.